# Find Main Container JSON Key Name via jQuery .ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, each

It seems like a simple question but I have not found the correct answer for it in all my searching. I have multiple JSON objects that look like this:

```
{
"crs_20868": [
    {
        "Thing": "foo",
        "StuffNum": "13",
        "Info1": [
            {
                "InfoColor": "Green",
                "InfoId": "33637"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Each will be returned via a successful `$.ajax()` GET. They will all contain different information, but will always start with the key name for the overall containing array for the data -- in this example, it's `crs_20868`. I never know at any given time what the main containing key name will be, though I can access it easily enough, since there will always be a single container array for each AJAX call. An `$.each()` loop gets me this name:

```
var contkey;
$.each(data, function(key, item){
   contkey = key;
});
console.log(contkey); // correctly returns 'crs_20868'
```

(Note this may not be the most efficient means of determining the containing key name, and I certainly welcome advice on how to best return that name -- but this works, sort of, as I'll get into below...)

I've proven by the console.log output that I do get the correct containing key name in my variable and it seems like I should be able to utilize `contkey` for all the tasks needed to access the contained data, even recognizing that it's a string. So, it's seems like this should work fine:

```
var thing = data.contkey[0].Thing;
$('#thingid1').append(thing);
```

But it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. Whereas, if I enter the name directly, i.e.:

```
var thing = data.crs_20868[0].Thing;
$('#thingid1').append(thing);
```

`foo` gets appended to my HTML ID `thingid1` fine. As suggested, however, I'll never know what that containing key name is when I run my AJAX call. So: how do I get that container name as a re-usable variable to access the object data contained in that main array, and is there a more efficient way of accessing it than my `$.each()` loop example above? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: try data[contkey][0].Thing

Comment: what exactly are you trying to loop? you have 2 arrays there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data doesn't have a property called contkey.  Instead, `data[contkey][0].Thing` should pop out what you're looking for.

As for the loop to find contkey in the first place, that's probably the way I'd end up doing it.

Comment: Awesome, @cnick -- I'm pretty clueless (could you tell?) about the syntax for objects and arrays. Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: np.  We all start somewhere.

Comment: BTW -- you definitely answered the question I posed, but I'm having a different issue with your solution when generating HTML from what I save out using your method, and it warranted a separate question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836537/error-using-localstorage-data-saved-from-json-for-dynamic-html-generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836537/error-using-localstorage-data-saved-from-json-for-dynamic-html-generation)